# Retrofit 2: Post request don't received by local server

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm using a .php file to receive requests that are sent by my Android application (Kotlin).

This is my implementation of the Retrofit logic

**RetrofitClient.kt (The Database)**

```
class RetrofitClient {

    companion object {

        private lateinit var INSTANCE: Retrofit
        private const val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/"

        private fun getRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {

            val http = OkHttpClient.Builder()

            if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
                INSTANCE = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(http.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }

            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun <S> createService(classService: Class<S>): S{
            return getRetrofitInstance().create(classService)
        }

    }

}
```

**PostService.kt (The Service)**

```
interface PostService {

    @POST("android-wait/sendPosts.php")
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    fun postRequest(@Body body: Map<String, Any>): Call<List<PostEntity>>

}
```

**PostEntity (The Entitiy)**

```
class PostEntity {

    @SerializedName("userId")
    var userId: Int = 0

    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int = 0

    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String = ""

    @SerializedName("body")
    var body: String = ""

}
```

**MainActivity.kt (For Requests in OnCreate Method)**

```
val body = mapOf<String, Any>(
            Pair("title", "This is a great Title"),
            Pair("body", "Lorem impsum dolor is awesome..."),
            Pair("userId", 765)
        )

val callPost: Call<List<PostEntity>> = service.postRequest(body)

callPost.enqueue(object : Callback<List<PostEntity>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<PostEntity>>,
                response: Response<List<PostEntity>>
) {
                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                    val list = response.body()
                    if (list != null && list.size > 0) {
                        Log.d("Response POST", "${list[0].id}")
                    }
                }
            }

override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<PostEntity>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Response POST FAIL", "$t")
            }
})
```

**sendPosts.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$dataJson = json_encode(array(
    'userId' => $_POST['userId'],
    'id' => 999,
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'body' => $_POST['body'],
));

echo $dataJson;

$file = fopen("return.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $dataJson);
fclose($file);
```

By default, this code works almost perfectly, as the request arrives at the server, as I can see that the `return.txt` file is created.

The problem is that the file is created at the same time that nothing is retrieved in `$_POST`:

> {"userId":null,"id":999,"title":null,"body":null}

Also, an error is returned in the `onFailure` method:

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
> JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
> 1 path $

How can i solve this problems?

Comment: It looks like the server JSON response is not valid. Can you show how the response body looks like?